# Why is auto-saving on Fifa 14 on Xbox 360 not working?

Tags: fifa-14

In career mode I can play about 5 - 6 games where the auto-save works perfectly. Then, for some reason, when I am finished playing and turn off the console, upon restarting it I have lost all of my progress.

This is very frustrating, can you please help?

Comment: Where are you saving your games to?   Internal HD or external device?  There could be a corruption somewhere.